# How to get menu sidebar to disappear and content to adjust using transforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So right now I'm making a dashboard with the list on the left, and the content on the right. Here's a snippet of my css of the two:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px #111 solid;
    position: absolute;
}

.content {
    width: 1480px;
    height: 100%;
/*    margin-left: 220px;*/
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(220px, 0px , 0px);
/*    transform: translate3d(220px, 0, 0);*/
}
```

And here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home").click(function(){
        $("#nav").slideToggle('fast'); 
        document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar').style.transform = "(0, 0, 0)"; 
        document.getElementsByClassName('content').style.transform = "(0, 0, 0)";  
        document.getElementsByClassName('content').style.webkitTransform = "(0, 0, 0)";  
        document.getElementsByClassName('content').style.MozTransform = "(0, 0, 0)";   
        document.getElementsByClassName('content').style.msTransform = "(0, 0, 0)";    
        document.getElementsByClassName('content').style.OTransform = "(0, 0, 0)";                  });


});
```

I'm trying to make it so that if I click a button above the content and sidebar, the sidebar stuff will disappear, and then the content part will stretch out and adjust to the screen. Likewise, if I clicked the same button again, the sidebar will come back up and the content will then adjust to the sidebar being visible. Right now, when I click the button the sidebar scrolls up and is gone, but the content part is being extremely stubborn and just doesn't move from its original position.

Something strange I found is that if I put:

```
    $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
```

last behind all of those transforms, the scrolling ability of the sidebar isn't even functional. If I click on the button, the sidebar doesn't even react, which leads me to believe that I'm not properly handling these transforms.

EDIT: note that #nav is just an id of the stuff in the sidebar. I would normally use .sidebar to scroll up, but it is slow whenever I try to make it disappear. With #nav, it's great both ways

Please help, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code for you.think this will help you.just copy,paste and try it. jquery has plugged online.so you need and internet connection to try the code or if you have linked jquery offline it will work fine.good luck

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Welcome !</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
      body{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    
      .maindiv{
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
        }
      .slidediv{
        width: 0%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
        position: absolute;
      }
    
      .content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:black;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    
      }
    
    </style>
    
    
     <body>
    
    <div class="maindiv">
      <div class="slidediv"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <button id="click" style="width:60px;height:30px;color:black;background-color:orange;font-size:13px;border-radius:8px;">Slider</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#click").click(function(){
        $("div.slidediv").animate({width:"30%"});
        $("div.content").animate({width: "70%"});
        $(this).hide();
      });
    
      $("div.slidediv").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({width :"0%"});
        $("div.content").animate({width:"100%"});
        $("#click").show();
      });
    
    </script>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

I have added another one with navigation.it will show how it when resize

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .maindiv{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
  .slidediv{
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    
  }

  .content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;

  }

div.navi{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0%;

}

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 3%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;

}

</style>


 <body>

<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="slidediv"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="navi">
      <button id="click" style="width:60px;height:30px;color:black;background-color:orange;font-size:13px;border-radius:8px;position:absolute;left:0;border:2px solid black;"> ||| </button>
      <ul>
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 



<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#click").click(function(){
    $("div.slidediv").animate({width:"30%"}).css({"box-shadow":"1px 2px 1px white"});
    $("div.content").animate({width: "70%"});
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $("div.slidediv").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width :"0%"});
    $("div.content").animate({width:"100%"});
    $("#click").show();
  });

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the animate function and got it to work! Well, at least it works one way haha. I need to now get it so that if I click the button  again, it'll revert. I'll take a look back into yours as it seems to have this functionality

Comment: always use your sizes with `%` so when screez resize, it affect to others same way.